# Convert ByteArray byte[] to File Object C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to have the file object of the following `result` variable

```
var data = ExportFactory.ExportDataJson(json, ExportToFormat.PDFiTextSharp4);
File.WriteAllBytes("bJson.pdf", data);
var result = File.ReadAllLines("bJson.pdf");
```

I searched with no result found out to solve this problem.
If anyone has an idea to help me out.

- PS: my byte array has a size of 1553

Comment: Is there any error in your code or what's your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "the file object"?

Comment: @D-Shih there is no error in my code the problem is that i get the byte[] contains only numbers with no info about the file (e.g filesize,filename,...) so i want the file object which have these info

Comment: @MohammedEhab I edit my answer you can try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to use [File.ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx).

- `File.ReadAllLines` opens a text file, reads all lines of the file, and then closes the file.
- `File.ReadAllBytes` opens a binary file, reads the contents of the file into a byte array, and then closes the file.

so if you want to read `.pdf`, I would use `File.ReadAllBytes` to read file be `byte[]`

You file is `.pdf`, you can try to use `iTextSharp` library `PdfReader` class to get the`Pdf` file info.

```
var data = ExportFactory.ExportDataJson(json, ExportToFormat.PDFiTextSharp4);
File.WriteAllBytes("bJson.pdf", data);
var dataBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes("bJson.pdf");
PdfReader result = new PdfReader(dataBuffer);
```

**EDIT**

I saw your comment. if you want to get *info about the file (e.g filesize,filename,...)*.

You can try to use [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class, `FileInfo` constructor parameter is the file path.

```
 FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("bJson.pdf");
 var fileSize= fileInfo.Length;
 var fileName = fileInfo.Name;
```